# Opening a file into a struct

Tags: c

I seem to be having an issue with opening a file containing information e.g student records and printing it using my struct.

Say I have student names, their IDs and grades in the txt file such as:

```
casnova 195843 A
and so on...
```

I defined my struct as:

```
struct student {
    char name[20];
    int ID;
    char Grade;
};
```

I want to load up this file using structs, and I am kind of lost as to what I should be doing.

My question is not asking how to do the question but basically a starting point as I am still fairly new to C programming, any tips/links are helpful :)

Comment: Um nothing really helpful, i'm not really sure as what to do :\

Comment: Doesn't you want to tag this question as homework? :p It looks like...

Comment: @user1393599, from your responses, I understand you lack very basic knowledge. Asking questions on stackoverflow will not get your anywhere because no one wants to write 100 pages of tutorial on everything! My suggestion is take a book on C from your library and start reading and learning from scratch.

Comment: Going through a few SO posts can clear all your doubts and would also help you for the correct starting for your problem.

Comment: -1: user1393599, if you know nothing of c, then this is not the place to ask. Read a book, tutorial, etc. Stackoverflow is not made to do your homework.

Answer (score 2):

> My question is not asking how to do the question but basically a
>   **starting point**

- Define an array of `struct student` an array of `char`
- Use `fopen` to open the file
- Use `fgets` in a `while` loop to read one line at a time (that's what the char array is for)
- Use `sscanf` to extract constituent members of said line. Test the value returned by `sscanf`. Alternatively you can use `strtok` and convert tokens as needed.

Comment: hmm, i don't quite follow. say i have 3 different students, i'll have '3' at the top of the list, is it possible to read that value and reapeat the loop that many times? how can i properly define the struct array?

Comment: can ya give me another hint? i'm relaly stuck! aha.

Answer (score 0):

The old answer is off topic and is erased.

---

Didn't noticed that was a text file.

You may want to find the answer of two things, or you may already know the answer:

1. read text file with fscanf
2. write date to a struct variable

---

If what's in the file is something like:

```
Tom 123 A
Dick 456 B
```

and you open the file with `fopen`, and get a `FILE *` called `fp`.

```
struct student s;

fscanf(fp, "%s %d %c", s.name, &s.ID, &s.Grade);
```

will fill the struct with the content in the file.

But you must make sure the content of the file is correct. Or you will have to do some complex parsing with the content of the file.

Comment: so what exactly does this do?

Comment: ?? The comments are not very congruent with the answer.. Was the answer completely erased and edited?

Comment: i want to read the information in a file, and use structs to print it out, i am completely lost as to what i should do :(